# Remove new line when appending to file

Tags: python, file, append, strip

I have an issue where when I append to a file, a newline is always added for some reason. This breaks my code. It is meant to be some sort of login system. I have searched for answers alot. Currently I have found the `.rstrip('\r')`, `.strip('\t')` and `.strip('\n')` have not worked.

Example:

I write to a file like this when it already has the contents `password1,username1<>`:

```
print("Create")
with open('database.txt', 'a') as database:
    username = input("Enter a username: ")
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
    combined = (password + "," + username + "<>")
    combined = combined.strip('\n')
    combined = combined.strip('')
    combined = combined.strip(' ')
    combined = combined.rstrip('\r')
    combined = combined.strip('\t')
    database.write(combined)
    database.close()

    #checking total number of users
    with open('usernum.txt', 'r+') as usernum:
        #the current number + 1 will be the number of the new user
        total_num_of_users = usernum.read()
        total_num_of_users = int(total_num_of_users) + 1
        #incrementing for future numbers
        total_num_of_users = str(total_num_of_users)
        usernum.truncate(0)
        usernum.write(total_num_of_users)
        usernum.close()

    #making a file containing the users place/number
    namefile = str(username) + '.txt'
    with open(namefile, 'w+') as usernum:
        usernum.write(total_num_of_users)
        usernum.close()
```

Please ignore the fact that the file is called database.txt lol. If my input is `username2` and `password2` my expected output is:

> password1,username1<>password2,username2<>

However instead I get:

> password1,username1<>
>
> password2,username2<>

Can anyone help me wth this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried your code but it works well without new line.

Comment: @JayPeerachai after testing it looks like it occurs sometimes, but not other times. It's weird, like dependent on how many users I've added. I need a method that works 100% of the time

Comment: Maybe this is not related to your problem, but I'd suggest you to remove the `close` statement. Using `with` doesn't require manual close because it is the proper way to manage resources. A file will be closed automatically.

Comment: Your requirement to not have newlines between individual entries is, frankly, crazy. POSIX mandates that text files should end with a newline, always. Keeping all your data in a single line just clutters the file and obscures the struture.